# XML Choice of elements, but of same type when maxOccurs is unbounded

Tags: xml, xsd

I am trying to define an element in an XML file using an XSD schema with a choice, which is not that hard:

```xml
    <xs:complexType abstract="true"
                    name="ESAPIObject">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="PropertyName"
                        type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="Condition"
                        minOccurs="1"
                        maxOccurs="unbounded">
...
            </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="BeamObject">
        <xs:complexContent>
            <xs:extension base="ESAPIObject">
                <xs:sequence/>
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="DoseObject">
        <xs:complexContent>
            <xs:extension base="ESAPIObject">
                <xs:sequence/>
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="StructureObject">
        <xs:complexContent>
            <xs:extension base="ESAPIObject">
                <xs:sequence/>
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:element name="Beam"
                type="BeamObject"/>
    <xs:element name="Dose"
                type="DoseObject"/>
    <xs:element name="Structure"
                type="StructureObject"/>

    <xs:group name="actualValueType">
        <xs:choice>
            <xs:element ref="Beam"/>
            <xs:element ref="Dose"/>
            <xs:element ref="Structure"/>
        </xs:choice>
    </xs:group>

    <xs:complexType name="SimpleConditionType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="ActualValue">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:choice>
                        <xs:group ref="actualValueType" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
                    </xs:choice>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
```

However the aggravating part is the fact that the choice element within `ActualValue` might repeat, but only if it is from the same type as previous ones?
So only either Structure elements or Beam elements or Dose elements not a mixture of them, e.g.:

```
  <ActualValue>
   <Structure />
   <Structure />
  </ActualValue>
```

or

```
  <ActualValue>
   <Beam />
   <Beam />
  </ActualValue>
```

or

```
  <ActualValue>
   <Dose />
   <Dose />
  </ActualValue>
```

But not:

```
  <ActualValue>
   <Structure />
   <Dose />
  </ActualValue>
```

I can not find a way to implement this in my XSD. Any suggestions?

Comment: That is strange. Your XSD works perfectly for me. Could you please put a full XSD text into the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I spotted a couple of mistakes in your XSD:

- You have defined a *repeating choice* instead of a *choice with repeating members*
- You have a redundant <xs:choice> around your group reference
- Your global group 'ActualValueType' should be 'ActualValueGroup' (a group is not a type, so the distinction matters)

In order to test your xsd more easily I made `ActualValue` a global element declaration.

After making those changes, I ended up with this:

```xml
    <xs:group name="actualValueGroup">
        <xs:choice>
            <xs:element ref="Beam" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            <xs:element ref="Dose" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            <xs:element ref="Structure" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xs:choice>
    </xs:group>

    <xs:element name="ActualValue">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:group ref="actualValueGroup" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
```

...which correctly accepts or rejects each of your examples.

Comment: Thanks, I think this might work. 

Actually `ActualValueType` is called like that as it is a type in the object model behind it, since this is used to deserialize XML to a object model in CSharp.